# How to count words in Map via Stream

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, collections, java-stream

I'm working with `List<String>` -- it contais a big text. Text looks like:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("The first line", "The second line", "Some words can repeat", "The first the second"); //etc
```

I need to calculate words in it with output:

```
first - 2
line - 2
second - 2
can - 1
repeat - 1
some - 1
words - 1
```

Words shorter than 4 symbols should be skipped, that's why "the" and "can" are not in the output. Here I wrote the example, but originally if the word is rare and entry < 20, i should skip this word. Then sort the map by Key in alphabetical order.
Using only streams, without "if", "while" and "for" constructions.

What I have implemented:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCount = Stream.of(list)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("\\p{Punct}| |[0-9]|…|«|»|“|„")))
                .filter(str -> (str.length() >= 4))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        i -> i.toLowerCase(),
                        i -> 1,
                        (a, b) -> java.lang.Integer.sum(a, b))
                );
```

wordCount contains Map with words and its entries. But how can I skip rare words? Should I create new stream? If yes, how can I get the value of Map? I tried this, but it's not correct:

```
 String result = Stream.of(wordCount)
         .filter(i -> (Map.Entry::getValue > 10));
```

My calculations shoud return a String:

```
"word" - number of entries
```

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example input and your expected output. Your approach so far only raises questions for me. It smells like an [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: maybe if I could guess it right, you need to `map` those entries to `String` and `join` them into one for the output.

Comment: i've added some input and outpeu to the text of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the stream that already done:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(
        "For the rabbit, it was a bad day.",
        "An Antillean rabbit is very abundant.",
        "She put the rabbit back in the cage and closed the door securely, then ran away.",
        "The rabbit tired of her inquisition and hopped away a few steps.",
        "The Dean took the rabbit and went out of the house and away."
);

Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = Stream.of(lines)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("\\p{Punct}| |[0-9]|…|«|»|“|„")))
        .filter(str -> (str.length() >= 4))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                String::toLowerCase,
                i -> 1,
                Integer::sum)
        );

System.out.println("Original:" + wordCounts);
```

Original output:

```
Original:{dean=1, took=1, door=1, very=1, went=1, away=3, antillean=1, abundant=1, tired=1, back=1, then=1, house=1, steps=1, hopped=1, inquisition=1, cage=1, securely=1, rabbit=5, closed=1}
```

You can do:

```
String results = wordCounts.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(wordToCount -> wordToCount.getValue() > 2) // 2 is rare
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).map(wordCount -> wordCount.getKey() + " - " + wordCount.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

System.out.println(results);
```

Filtered output:

```
away - 3, rabbit - 5
```

Comment: In the output the standart symbol "=" between Key and Value is used. How can I make an  output as a String: 
away - 3,
rabbit - 5 ?

Comment: @CatherinZetaJones I have changed the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't exclude any values that are less than `rare` until you have computed the frequency count.

Here is how I might go about it.

- do the frequency count (I chose to do it slightly differently than you).
- then stream the entrySet of the map and filter out values less than a certain frequency.
- then reconstruct the map using a `TreeMap` to sort the words in lexical order

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(....);

int wordRarity = 10; // minimum frequency to accept
int wordLength = 4; // minimum word length to accept
        
Map<String, Long> map = list.stream()
        .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(
                str.split("\\p{Punct}|\\s+|[0-9]|…|«|»|“|„")))
        .filter(str -> str.length() >= wordLength)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase, 
                Collectors.counting()))
        // here is where the rare words are filtered out.
        .entrySet().stream().filter(e->e.getValue() > wordRarity)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                (a,b)->a,TreeMap::new));
    }
```

Note that the `(a,b)->a` lambda is a merge function to handle duplicates and is not used.  Unfortunately, one cannot specify a Supplier without specifying the merge function.

The easiest way to print them is as follows:

```
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%s - %s%n",
                e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

Comment: Although your regular expression will work just fine on the split, you man want to change it to `\\p{Punct}|\\s+|[0-9]|…|«|»|“|„`  This changes the `| |` to `|\\s+|` and thus splits on one or more white space characters (including tabs).  This has the effect of not streaming empty values caused by adjacent spaces.  You can test it out by simply splitting some words separated by white space and seeing the difference.